# Round to half integer (eg 0.5, 23.5)

Tags: javascript, rounding

I was wondering if it is possible to round to half integers with JavaScript (half integers only).

```
0.36 -> 0.5
23.667774 -> 23.5
0 -> 0.5
23 -> 23.5
22.999999999 -> 22.5
```

Thank you.

Comment: Float you mean? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: do you want 2 -> 2.5 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your current description, it sounds like all you really want to do is offset the rounding:

```
var foo = function foo (n) {return Math.round(n + 0.5) - 0.5;}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you sir.